# Converstion from into to timestamp in Hive or Impala

Tags: date, hive, timestamp, impala

Is there is a simple way to convert a int to timestamp data type in Impala or Hive.

I am using the below code to convert int to timestamp but I don't think its a efficient way.

```
20180520

CAST(concat(substring(CAST(datalake_date as string),1,4),'-',substring(CAST(datalake_date as string),5,2),'-',substring(CAST(datalake_date as string),7,2)) 
     AS TIMESTAMP)
```

--- For extracting Year ---

```
,date_part('Year',
CAST(concat(substring(CAST(datalake_date as string),1,4),'-',substring(CAST(datalake_date as string),5,2),'-',substring(CAST(datalake_date as string),7,2)) 
     AS TIMESTAMP)
          ) datalake_date
```

2018

Answer (score 0):

You can parse directly to unix timestamp like this

```
select unix_timestamp('20180520', 'yyyyMMdd');
```

After that, you have several UDFs to manipulate your date, extract year, day, etc/

Comment: The format you are using is wrong one. Check this: select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180520', 'YYYYmmDD'));
Returns
2017-12-31 00:05:00 - Surprise isn't it? Correct format is yyyyMMdd

Answer (score 0):

Use `unix_timestamp(string date, string pattern)` to convert given date [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to seconds passed from 1970-01-01. Then use from_unixtime() to convert to required [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( '20180520','yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Returns:

```
OK
2018-05-20
Time taken: 0.057 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Simple way to extract year is using substr:

```
select substr('20180520',1,4);
OK
2018
Time taken: 3.062 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Or after above (see first query) conversion to the standard hive format 'yyyy-MM-dd' you can use `year()`, `date_format` functions